# Selenium webdriver identify button and clicking on it using Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

currently im trying to automate filling in a rather large webform with selenium and java. im using the firefox webdriver. i have firebug installed and xpath checker (on firefox).

My problem is clicking on a button after logging in to a website. the login part is no problem. its a username/password and submit action.

ive tried various FindElement methods and im thinking it should be Xpath. i simply dont know how to identify the button since it has no name property.

xpath checker: id('sectiondiv_81')/x:input

```html
<div id="sectiondiv_81" class="ax-boxcontent" style="">
<input class="Button" type="button" onclick="window.location='/Apps/app_editopportunity.jsp?appid=103184&nextlevel=1&companyid=&opportunityid=0&opportunitytypeid=13997&defaultstatusid=12824&providertoken=Sml3L21uJDk!HkITNmAzGDUlHhd2GxoXH2JcU0JFal9AQVxWHwQIUxkbbFFfXhI~'" value="Apply for a scientific research project">
<br>
</div>
```

where it concerns the button with value 'Apply for a scientific research project'.

i would greatly appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only button inside of , you might be able to find it by XPath like:

```
("//div[contains(@id, 'sectiondiv_81')]/input[contains(@class, 'Button')]")
```

or

```
("//input[contains(@value, 'scientific research project')]")
```

Comment: cheers for the reply. i get this error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@id, 'sectiondiv_81')]/input[contains(@class, 'Button')]"}
the code i used: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'sectiondiv_81')]/input[contains(@class, 'Button')]")).click();

Comment: That might be because of multiple elements with same Xpath. Give it a try with value search method , I have updated my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Can we look the full website for analyze it?

I recommend you Firebug and Firepath to check the XPath like that:

```
//div[contains(@id, 'sectiondiv_81')]/input[contains(@class, 'Button')]
```

you will be able to check the "section" or "sections" in the website that accords with your Xpath

Also you can get the XPath with Firebug, right click -> Inspect in FirePath

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to use digits, indexes if it possible, because it makes xpath query not flexible for possible ui changes.
It's better to use any element attributes, which give you unique result.

```
//input[@type='button'][contains(@value, 'Apply')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` element is a sibling of the `<div>` element with an ID so try using the XPath following-sibling command like so:

```
WebElement myButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sectiondiv_81']/following-sibling::input"));
myButton.click();
```

This comes from the W3C [XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths).